# Android in-app Billing always reply with error 3: BILLING_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase, play-billing-library

Our app have in-app purchases. Our tests worked fine with real payment methods too, but from abroad customers (Asia in particular) we constantly receive error reports. The Google Play Billing Android library returns response code [`BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` (3)](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference#billing-codes) most if not all times. Dozens of users have tried to purchase, but nearly no-one had success.

The code simply queries SKU details using a [`BillingClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient) and then initiates the billing flow, just like the described in the official tutorial.

On the Play Console we have setup all required SKUs, and they're all available for all regions our app is present.

What can be the causes for `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` response code? Is it possible that *all* users from certain geographic regions get that code and cannot complete the purchase?

I find difficult to debug the issue, since on our end everything works fine all the time.

Answer (score 9):

In my experiences, this response code is returned if Play Services are not available (you can test it yourself by installing your APK on an Amazon Fire device), or if the user did not set up a Google account.

Answer (score 0):

It can be some of the prerequisites below are not satisfied. In my case, is the fourth. Read this [article](https://bewaters.me/limxtop/2023/11/11/Google-Play-Store-In-App-Billing/) for more information.

1. Upload the application to Closing Testing, no need to publish at this stage. (Internal Testing may be sufficient, but not verified).
2. Create SKUs, note that the ID should match the ID of the application request.
3. Add the tester's mailbox, which is the Google account login to the device to test the app SKU.
4. Switch License Respond to LICENSED (Path: play console homepage -> Setup -> License testing).
5. The Application ID for uploading Closing Testing needs to be the same as the Application ID for local debugging.

Comment: _"Switch License Respond to LICENSED"_: I found that dropdown in the console, but it's not clear to me what exactly it does, and why it should fix that issue; I can't find any documentation from Google, do you know something more? Thanks.